# setting a time delay between two frame when animation a sprite sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a5h/

As you can see the animation of the sprite sheet when the player is not moving is too fast so I was trying to make it slow by declaring two variable `lastRenderTime: 0,RenderRate: 50000`

but my code is not working and it seem I have a misunderstanding of the algorithm I am using so can anyone lay me a hand to how can I fix it?

```
if (!this.IsWaiting) {
    this.IsWaiting = true;
    this.Pos = 1 + (this.Pos + 1) % 3;
}
else {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now - this.lastRenderTime < this.RenderRate) this.IsWaiting = false;
       this.lastRenderTime = now;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your logic is wrong. You were using the wrong operator `<` instead of `>`. Also, you needed to update the `lastRenderTime` only when the condition is statisfied, otherwise it keeps getting updated and the value of `now - this.lastRenderTime` never ends up becoming more than 20 or so.

```
if (!this.IsWaiting) {
    this.IsWaiting = true;
    this.Pos = 1 + (this.Pos + 1) % 3;
}
else {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (now - this.lastRenderTime > this.RenderRate) { 
        this.IsWaiting = false;
        this.lastRenderTime = now;
    }
}
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a5h/7/).